# Using a powerline adapter and wireless bridge together as failover or loadbalancing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, powerline-networking

I have two routes via ethernet. One is more stable but slow, the other is fast but might disconnect. What solutions are available to have a load balancer or fail over? The routes are both from a single router.

My current setup is:
pfSense -> Wireless AP -> SwitchA -> powerline A
powerline B -> SwitchB -> PCs in room

Powerline A-B gets 20mbit
Basically I want to add a wireless bridge that also connects to switch B. 
powerline B -> SwitchB -> PCs in room
Wireless Bridge -> SwitchB -> PCs in room

The switch by itself doesn't know which route to use (I assume), would a dual wan router with disabled DHCP work in this case or there a better solution?

Comment: Maybe DDWRT or Tomato has something. Not sure how though. Otherwise it's perhaps expensive stuff like a Cisco or Juniper router. Or, some software not sure which. I'd bet on DDWRT/Tomato -a router that supports that or that firmware.

Comment: If you end up needing something even more advanced than DD-WRT but don't want to spend the money on the expensive Cisco/Juniper stuff, then I'd highly recommend installing pfSense on a computer with two network cards. https://www.pfsense.org/

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided nearly enough information to go on - particularly how the "disconnect" works.     Making huge assumptions there are a few ways to deal with this -

1. Ensure the more reliable route is less preferred and set the faster but less reliable 
   connection up in such a way that the interface (or at least its route) disappears when
   its not available - this will provide automatic failover and give you largely the best
   of both worlds - but it assumes you can make the route disappear (which is not
   hard if you are using PPP.  (Note that ethernet does not preclude the use of PPP,
   PPPoE is very common)
2. Use dynamic routing like BGP (or OSPF or RIP, but in reality it will be BGP on
   the assumption your routes go to different providers).  This of-course assumes your
   router is BGP capable, you own rights to IP space and both  providers will play
   together.
3. Set up source routing so packets can go through either connection depending on the
   source IP (or mark) assigned to them.   Then balance this connection.  Again, there
   are multiple ways to do this depending on what you are trying to do and your
   hardware ability, but include:

   1. Routes which require low bandwidth or high reliability go through the slow 
      connection.  "Nice to haves" go through the fast connection.
   2. Get an reliable offsite connection (virtual server), set up 2 VPN's to the
      server - one through each link, aggregate the links as and available and 
      route everything across them.   This probably offers the best of both worlds
      but requires quite a bit of skill and, of-course, a fast connection on the
      other side.   [ And yes, I know someone doing just this, so its quite
      practical with the knowledge ]

In order to do any of this stuff you need a decent router - but decent could be a Linux based embedded system (I've done all of these things at one time or another using Linux).  The exact howtos are not really amenable to a Superuser question as they require an in-depth understanding of networking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow your diagram, but assuming you're talking about local networking, and not two seperate WAN uplinks, I suggest get decent switches that support OSPF, and let them do the hard work.

OSPF correctly configured will also occasionally exceed the bandwidth of a single link depending on your network topology (consider 4 nodes as 2 pairs, each node wired to a switch, and each pair also cross-connected), while other setups won't.